# Basement flooding due to a hole/gap along the exterior wall

Tags: waterproofing, water-damage

Just found there is water mark and mold in the basement in a 6 feet by 6 inch area near the baseboard.  After a quick check and some photo comparison it seems that it is due to a hole near the external wall at the same location.

So what happened was this area was fixed years before with those black water barrier thing.  I think when the HVAC company replaced the air conditioning, they just took away the old metal bracket by brute force and tear some of the shielding, also left the screw hole unfilled. Eventually water keep seeping through there and cause a over footing.

What should be done to fix it outside and inside? Can I simply fill the hole (if so, what material) outside, and do I need to cut the whole baseboard plus the surrounding carpet and drywall?

[image]

Comment: Usually water coming in means a crack or a hole.  It is best to have it fixed from the outside and usually requires digging down, you might be lucky if it is just at/near the surface.  Inside work is drying and/or removing damaged materials.  Will need to find where and how the water is coming in, but usually very close to the wet area/s.

Comment: Simply adding more black rubber sealant will work again. For a while. Then you'll be right back in the same boat. Odds are good that the water getting in here is washing out the soil below the (grey part, not tan part, concrete?) horizontal piece in your picture. There is now enough water & pressure accumulated near a weak spot in the wall that it's able to seep through and get your basement wet. Unfortunately, it will likely take some digging up the outside to actually see what's going on in order to properly fix this long term.